# Flash Bug? Dynamic Text randomly scales

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm having this problem where dynamic text in my flash 10 (AS3) game application will shrink in size randomly for certain players. You might have 5 TextFields in a row that are basically all the same (such as table headings) and 2 of the 5 texts will scale down.  It has a glow effect, but I don't believe that is related. There's nothing in my AS3 code that modifies the scaling, width, or height of any of those fields.

Has anyone else experienced random scaling of text?

So far it's only been reported with Google Chrome Browser, but it might be happening inside other browsers as well.

Comment: Just to clarify more, when I say the size shrinks, I mean it REALLY shrinks. Like 50% or more smaller. It's random and quite rare. Only a small handful of 10,000 users has reported the problem, and I've only seen something similar myself once. In my case the font size grew larger, and it was on a dynamically-loaded SWF MovieClip that had no AS3 code acting upon it.

Comment: I wonder if it could be related to the fact that my fonts are embedded  in a separate SWF and then in my main SWF library, the fonts are set to [x] Import for runtime sharing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen this problem happen for a while, so I think the bug might have been fixed in Flash Player 10.3

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes sub-pixel placement gives me these kinds of errors. Flash happily places things on say 324.2x422.6 which brings havok to my layouts. To solve this I add in placement logic to guarantees full pixel only placement of my objects.

I do not know if this would cause your problem, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: So you're saying when text is placed on a sub-pixel location that it might change point size? That sounds like a serious bug in flash if that's the case. I'm not currently placing fonts on integer pixel locations because I didn't think that was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the font-embedding. Did you embed the fonts correctly in your swf? If you don't embed the font and the user doesn't have the font you used, it will show some default font which might appear smaller.

If you don't know how to embed fonts: http://www.flabell.com/blog/668/embedding-fonts-in-flash-cs4

Comment: Good thinking, but that's not it, the fonts are embedded properly. The text appears in the correct font, with the correct effects, they are just a different point size than what is specified in the FLA file.

Comment: I wonder if it could be related to the fact that my fonts are embedded  in a separate SWF and then in my main SWF library, the fonts are set to [x] Import for runtime sharing.